# Temporal Tables Manually Update Data

Tags: sql-server, version-control, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

Using SQL Server 2019, can I push data (snapshot data) from the Current (Temporal Table) to the History Table only when I want to rather than it happening automatically after every row commit? I understand that Temporal Tables are designed to record all data changes to a row - great for auditing. But what if I don't want to save all changes? What If I only want to 'baseline' data on a set of tables every week, (or when the user wants to) and I don't care what changes are made during the week? I know you can disable and enable the temporal tables, but that is more of a high level control, and the architecture is multi-tenanted,and different tenants will snapshot at different times.

Or perhaps Temporal Tables is the wrong tool for me? My use case is as follows - A user creates a mathematical model altering many parameters, they do this many times over many days, persisting to the database with every change. When they get it right they press 'Baseline' Everything is stored. They then continue with the next changes to the next baseline. At any point they can compare the difference between any two baselines. I only retain the data at the date of 'Baseline'. This would require that I move the data to the temporal history table manually..or let it go automatically and purge everything in between two baselines, seems a waste of DB resources.

Comment: I would say use Change Data Capture instead, set it to clear after two weeks, then have an Agent job running once a week to sum up the changes for the week and dump it into a permanent history table. Another option judging by your use case is just to manually insert the changes to the history table when the new Baseline happens

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. I am far from an expert on SQL Sever, and was not aware of Change Data Capture. I guess Temporal Tables are the new buzz and so all my research only ever turned up stuff on Temporal Tables, and the not the old tried and true CDC. Thanks for your help